# Existence of a Non-Constant Bounded Function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $U$ be a connected open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ \ $\{-1,1\}$ such that $n(\gamma,1)=n(\gamma,-1)$ for every closed curve $\gamma$ in $U$. Show that there exists a bounded holomorphic function on $U$.Here $n(\gamma,a)$ denotes the winding number of $\gamma$ with respect to $a$. I have got no idea how to get on with this problem. Thanks for any help.

Comment: So are you looking for hints? You surely have some thoughts

Comment: This will mean there's a branch of $$\ln\frac{z-1}{z+1}$$ on $U$. Is that helpful?

Comment: Ok, let me try with this .If I face any difficulties, I shall consult you.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Probably I'm just being slow again, but I don't see how that does it. Of course it "must" help, since the existence of that logarithm iis precisely equivalent to the hypothesis...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the principle branch of $z\,(1 - \sqrt{1-z^{-2}})$. In other words, one of the branches of $z - \sqrt{z^2-1}$ will be bounded.